# Spring Boot, Debian, Embedded Tomcat close external port

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, debian, port, iptables

This is my Spring Boot application properties:

```
server.port: 8081
```

On Debian 9 I run Spring Boot war with Embedded Tomcat in the following way:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar api-0.0.1.war
```

[image]

Right after that, I can access the application by the following url:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/v1.0
```

I'd like to close external access to 8081 port and leave only access to this port from the internal system.

I order to achieve this, I applied the following rule:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 8081 -j DROP
/sbin/service iptables save
```

but right now I'm unable to access url http://localhost:8081/api/v1.0 from another application on the same machine.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow the localhost post.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --destination-port 8081 -j ACCEPT`